# Is there any way to see all my answers quoted by some other users?

Tags: support, answers, quotes, linked-questions

Recently I saw an answer from another user where they had quoted one of my answers within theirs. It felt nice.

So that had me wondering, is there any way to see all my answers that are quoted elsewhere by some other users?

I know I can go through all my answers and see the linked posts which may or may not show me the desired results but that is kind of hectic. What I am looking for is a list. I think SEDE's might be the only way, if any.

Comment: What would you consider a substantial quote? Anything after `>` that matches anything in any of your answers?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Anything that provides a link to my answer I suppose. The string matching could be inaccurate, e.g. Me and some other guy quoting the same source. The links however are a better way I reckon. But then again, links can be different depending on whether you came from front page, search, comment or share url feature. Anything that contains "Post Id" of one of my posts which is an answer would be a better bet I suppose

Comment: I quess getting a table of all your answers and then searching all post bodies for links containing post IDs from that table might be the best way to go. (And of course, cue standard recommendation that you might reach a broader audience of SEDE-knowledgable people by asking this general SE question on [meta.se].)

Comment: `SELECT Id  AS [Post Link] FROM Posts 
WHERE PostTypeId = 2
AND OwnerUserId != ##UserId##
AND Body LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT Id FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND 
                    OwnerUserId = ##UserId##),'%')`

Something like this of course. This one doesn't work tho because the subquery returns more than one results and I need to evaluate the body against all of my answers.

Comment: @TARS I guess I could take it to MSE. What should I do with this one? Leave open and then answer with whatever I might find there?

Comment: I don't know. Depends on personal taste, I guess. *I* would just have gone to [meta.se] to begin with. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this I used some arguably pretty narrow definitions for what counts as a quote. I assumed that a quote is, at very least, a link back to the original post. This link has to have the following format: `scifi.stackexchange.com/a/<postid>`. The query then takes all posts that contain such links, checks whether they link back to one of your posts, at reports that.

The results are the original post id, the quoting post id, and whether or not you self-quoted in that specific instance or not.

The tally seems to be:

- 10 quotes by others
- 24 quotes by yourself

[**The Query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/779744/posts-by-aegon-quoted-with-url)

Comment: By the way, you know that you can use the `as [Post Link]` magic column name in order to get a neat link to the post (complete with title text) instead of a bare ID? It might also be a good idea to make the user in question an input parameter. I don't particularly care about Ageon's answers. ;-)

Comment: @TARS I was aware of the feature, but didn't know how to use it. Thanks :)